# ATSAME51 DMAC basic operation, channel transfer error

Tags: arm, cortex-m, dma

I'm trying to perform a basic memory-to-memory transfer using the DMAC on a ATSAME51 (ARM Cortex M4).

I have an array srcArr with 3 bytes that I want to transfer to an array destArr, after configuring the DMAC and attempting the transfer, the channel transfer error bit in the CHINTFLAG register is set (pg 401, datasheet link below).

The datasheet, [here](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/aemDocuments/documents/MCU32/ProductDocuments/DataSheets/SAM-D5x-E5x-Family-Data-Sheet-DS60001507.pdf), describes this behavior as a bus error (pg 353) but does not expand on why it would occur or how to avoid it.

```
#include "sam.h"
#include <drivers/io.h>


DmacDescriptor descriptorDmac[32];
DmacDescriptor writeBackDmac[32];
uint8_t destArr[3];
uint8_t srcArr[3] = {0xAA, 0xBB, 0xCC};

int main(void)
{
    ioSetPinDirOut(PORTB, LED_PIN);                                     //set debug led pin as an output.
    ioPinOutClr(PORTB, LED_PIN);                                        //turn led off.

    DMAC->DBGCTRL.reg = 1;                                              //DMA run while in debug mode.

                                    
    DMAC->BASEADDR.reg = (uint32_t)&descriptorDmac;                     //base address for descriptors.
    DMAC->WRBADDR.reg = (uint32_t)&writeBackDmac;                       //descriptor write back address.
    DMAC->CTRL.reg |= DMAC_CTRL_LVLEN0;                                 //handle level 0 transfers.
    
    DMAC->Channel[0].CHCTRLA.reg = DMAC_CHCTRLA_TRIGACT_TRANSACTION     //One beat transaction per trigger.
                                    | DMAC_CHCTRLA_TRIGSRC_DISABLE      //software trigger source.
                                    | DMAC_CHCTRLA_RUNSTDBY;            //run on standby.   
    
    descriptorDmac[0].BTCTRL.reg = DMAC_BTCTRL_BEATSIZE_BYTE            //8 bit beat size.
                                | DMAC_BTCTRL_VALID                     //valid descriptor.
                                | DMAC_BTCTRL_DSTINC                    //increment destination address.
                                | DMAC_BTCTRL_SRCINC;                   //increment source address.
    descriptorDmac[0].BTCNT.reg = 3;                                    //transfer 3 beats.
    descriptorDmac[0].SRCADDR.reg = (uint32_t)&srcArr;              //Set source address.
    descriptorDmac[0].DSTADDR.reg = (uint32_t)&destArr;             //Set destination address.
    
    DMAC->CTRL.bit.DMAENABLE = 1;                                       //Enable the DMA.
    DMAC->Channel[0].CHCTRLA.bit.ENABLE = 1;                            //enable channel 0.
    DMAC->SWTRIGCTRL.reg = 1;                                           //software trigger on channel 0.
    
    /*At this point, I would expect destArr[0] == srcArr[0] but
    instead DMAC->Channel[0].CHINTFLAG.bit.TERR is set. Nothing else.*/
    
    ioPinOutSet(PORTB, LED_PIN);                                        //turn led on.
    
    while (1) 
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: Can this DMA peripheral do memory-to-memory transfers? (some can't).  Also, declare those arrays volatile or else the compiler could optimize things in a way you don't want.

Comment: DMA has nothing to do with arm nor cortex-m.  The title question is very confusing this is a ATSAME51 question, arm has nothing to do with it at all.

Comment: @old_timer title revised, thanks for suggestion.

Comment: @TomV datasheet says it can do memory to memory. Will do with the arrays. Thanks.